# Error when install ionic app on Android device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have create my ionic app and run on Android emulator (Android 7.x).it work correctly,but when I try to install on Android box (Android 6.0.1) i got error

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: @yushin  "App not installed" (On samsung device C9 pro android 8.0 and android box android 6.0.1)  but on my huawei p10 plus and mate9 can run correctly

Comment: do you have any other apps the you receently developed installed on it?

Comment: @yushin may be not , i didn't see any icon on app drawer

Comment: sometime it refuses to install if they are apps with conflicting ids.

Comment: just check to see if the cordova version you are using is compatible with the android version and make sure you have installed the similar android version installed in android studio.

Comment: @yushin i use cordova 7.1.0 check by cordova -v

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your testing device is on the same version of your compiled apk sdk or it is in a version ahead of it.

For example, an app built for Android 7.1.0 will not run on Android 6.1.0 but an app built for Android 6.1.0 will run on both 6.1.0 and 7.1.0 and so on.

As a default approach the newer versions of ionic cli ships aways with the latest Android sdk version, which current is 7.1.0, if youl'd like to use an older one you need to remove the platform and add it again, you can do it within these commands:

Remove the platform

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

Then add it again with your desired android version

```
ionic cordova platform add android@6.1.0
```

For this example I'm using the 6.1.0 version but feel free to change it to another sdk version.